# Genreate phpDoc automatically

Tags: php, phpdoc

I would like to be able to integrate a the documentation generator from within my web interface.

I had a look at the `docbuilder`project which is a web-based generator provided with phpDoc itself, but I could not identify for sure what was the command that was actually triggering the beginning of the process.

Do you know where I could get some help finding how to execute the phpDoc script programmatically?

PS: I am running PHP on IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Docs should be generated by the integration system, i.e. [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [phpUnderControl](http://phpundercontrol.org/). They provide tasks for it.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, but I'm looking to really be able to create it on demand

Comment: you also said you wanted to execute it automatically :)